# Issues with notation of Ito Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

How should I interoperate $X_{t_j}$, does usually when I previously have seen double subscript it refer to having multidimensions.

In this case it looks like we are splitting up t into sections. 
In other words we could have that t goes from 0 to T, in steps of t.

however, is the second subscript referring to splitting up [0,t] into furter increments?

[image]

Comment: $X_t$ is a (random) function of $t.$ $X_{t_i}$ is that function evaluated at $t=t_i.$ The $t_i$ are an evenly spaced sequence of sample points in the interval... compare to the evaluation points for a Riemann integral or something like that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So I could consider it being the ith element of $X_t$ ?

Comment: No... that's not what I said.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Would you be able to write more in depth answer to the solution provided to this answer, where he uses the term ith element.: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710012/proving-exb-s-b-t4-nn2t-s2

Comment: They are referring to the $i$-th component of an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion which is a completely different concept. Their solution looks right (and is an elaboration of Did's suggestion in the comments) and I don't think I could improve on it.

Comment: In this example in this question, the $i$ refers to the $i$-th time step in a discretization of the time axis. In other words we're taking a function defined on some interval, but only looking at a finite number of points (and then taking a limit as we go to finer and finer spaced points in order to recover information about the continuous time function... as we do in, say, the Riemann or Stieljes integral)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Thank you for taking the time, this really helps me understand what is going on. I have one more question, in the case of the multi dimensional Brownian motion, what I dont get is: If I look at $B_t$, and we say we have discrete number of case $B_t$={$x_1$$,x_2$ to whatever number of cases there are} However, from that question what I see is I have B_t and B_s, now does that mean that s and t are to different dimensions.

Comment: In other words I dont see why the ith subject refer to ith dimension, is it simply that $B_s^1$ ={vector of random numbers} and $B_s^2$={another vector of random numbers}

Comment: $s$ and $t$ are different times. You can view the time as a dimension if you wish, but if so it is a completely orthogonal dimension to the components of $B.$ Note the other problem makes no mention or use of discrete time, so the time index is continuous there... so $B^1_s$ is a vector of sorts, but it has an uncountably infinite number of components.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, Yes, that make sense, so in other words $B_s$ is simply $B(s)$ and $B(s)^i$ is used if you have several Brownian motions. $B_s^i$ where 
Bs1 is a vector of sorts, but it has an uncountably infinite number of components. and Bs2 is another vector of sorts?

Comment: Yes, but a simpler thing to say, more in keeping with the usual way this is talked about is that each of the components $B^i_t$ is a function of time (or a function on some interval), or that the whole thing B_t is a vector-valued function of time. The individual components are all brownian motions, sometimes correlated (though they are assumed independent in that other question).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Perfect, I need to be carefull when I read Bernt Oksendals book, as he uses $X_{t_i}$ for both discrete increment and multidimensional case. Obviously with more explanation, but I got tricked to think that the subscript earlier in the book which was for the multidimensional case was still the same as when he uses the subscript in this question I have posted here.